# What is the link between the parity check matrix, double-error-correcting codes and APN permutations?

Tags: symmetric, s-boxes, coding-theory

I am currently reading a research paper (linked below) which mentions that a map $f:V:=GF(2^{m}) \rightarrow V$ which vanishes at 0 is APN if it satisfies the condition that it is a binary code $C_{f}$ with parity check matrix 
$H_{f} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\dots & \omega^{j} & \dots \\
\dots & f(\omega^{j}) & \dots 
\end{bmatrix}$
that is double-error-correcting (i.e. no fewer than 5 columns sum to 0).

From other sources that I found double-error-correcting also means that the minimum distance of the code should be 5.

However, I do not understand how all these definitions tie in together. Specifically, I do not understand how "no fewer than 5 columns sum to 0" ties in with the minimum distance of the code should be 5". Further, it would be great if anyone could clarify what "minimum distance 5" means.

[An APN Permutation in Dimension 6](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265815787_An_APN_permutation_in_dimension_six)

Comment: If fewer than 5 columns summed to zero, say 4 columns did,  then a codeword with 1's in those 4 positions and zeroes everywhere else would satisfy the parity check and would contradict the minimum distance being 5.

Answer (score 1):

This quite technical connection was ultimately proved in the paper

> C. Carlet, P. Charpin and V. Zinoviev. Codes, bent functions and permutations suitable for DES-like cryptosystems. *Designs, Codes and Cryptography* 15(2), pp. 125–156, 1998.

See also the paper by the same authors plus Dobbertin in the *IEEE Transactions on Information Theory*, around the same time. I'll give an executive summary in its classical form without all the equivalences discovered later.

In pseudorandom sequence design, the *Gold Sequences* have the form
$$
g_t=T(a z^t)+ T(z^{(2^k+1)t}), \quad t\geq 0
$$
where $T$ is the trace map from $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ to $\mathbb{F}_{2},$ $z$ is a primitive element in $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ and $gcd(n,k)=1.$

The sequence $T(az^t)$ is generated by a primitive LFSR corresponding to the characteristic polynomial $M_z(x)$ of $z$ and has period $2^n-1.$ The sequence $g_t$ is a sum of this sequence with its decimation by $2^k+1.$

Sequences taken with all their shifts form cyclic codes.

The Gold sequences viewed as a cyclic code in classical form have $k=1$, thus they are generated by the product $M_z(x)M_{z^3}(x).$

This means that the zeroes of this code are the union of those of $M_z$
$$
\{z,z^2,z^4,\ldots z^{2^{n-1}}\},
$$
and of $M_{z^3}:$
$$
\{z^3,z^6,z^{12},\ldots z^{3\cdot 2^{n-1}}\},
$$
thus have the 4 consecutive zeroes $\{z,z^2,z^3,z^4\}$ giving a cyclic BCH code of minimum distance $d=4+1=5.$